# Identifying a blocking strategy

Tags: c#, multithreading, blocking

I have a `Refresh()` method that refreshes a collection of name/value pairs in a single instance of a class (it's an application-wide property bag, resolved via a UnityContainer).

This `Refresh()` method can be called from multiple threads at the same time. I need to implement a blocking strategy so that any concurrent calls to the same method all get blocked and then released at the same time.

So the flow will be:

- the first caller executes the `Refresh()` method
- any concurrent caller will block
- once the first caller is finished, it *and all the blocked concurrent callers* will return
- released concurrent callers will not re-execute the guts of the method as there is no need to
- concurrent callers cannot be released early (i.e. they cannot return immediately) as the `Refresh()` method is still being executed by the first caller (and therefore the name/value collection is still changing)

Is there an established name for this locking/blocking strategy? I have an idea on how to implement this, but I need to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It is called a Cache.

Comment: @Aron the data could be considered a crude cache, there are other terminologies for it too. But terminology is not my issue... think of it this way: how would you prevent multiple callers all refreshing the cache at the same time?

Comment: My point is that it is a solved problem. Assuming that data is wanted, and the query is pure. Then it is simply a case of bringing in a caching library, with the features you want.

Comment: The best code is no code at all, you are reinventing the wheel and the first step to avoiding reinventing the wheel is to call it a wheel.

Comment: @Aron, I agree, however using a cache is not feasible (this is a very targeted change in a very large distributed app), and suggesting a cache doesn't actually answer the question. By *'re-inventing the wheel'* I mean I want to use an existing named locking/blocking pattern rather than come up with something hybrid but almost the same.

Comment: One strange option is to `await` [on the same task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820388/is-it-ok-to-await-the-same-task-from-multiple-threads-is-await-thread-safe) - result would not be exactly what you are asking, but may be an option if the rest of the code is async...

Comment: I've implemented the same strategy to great success, but I can't tell you a name for it, only that it has worked in a production application of mine for 3+ years now without issue.

Comment: I know you rejected the idea of introducing a cache, but there is already a well-tested one in the .NET Framework. Nothing new to install, no additional operational considerations. If you don't want to use it, have a look at it's source code for inspiration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Hi @EricJ.- while I could hook a cache in behind the class that doesn't solve this particular issue. The Refresh() method refetches the values from a data store, and this is functionality that a standard cache doesn't have.