# What happens when multiple parallel threads await the same Task instance which then throws?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Reading through [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820388/is-it-ok-to-await-the-same-task-from-multiple-threads-is-await-thread-safe) prompted me to think about what happens exception-wise when the awaited task throws. Do all "clients" get to observe the exception? I admit I may be confusing a couple of things here; that's the reason I'm asking for clarification.

I'll present a concrete scenario... Let's say I have a server with a global collection of long-running `Task` instances, started by clients. After starting one or more tasks, a client can query their progress and retrieve results when they become available, as well as any errors that might occur.

Tasks themselves may perform very different business-specific things - normally, no two are quite the same. However, if one of the clients does attempt to start the same task as another had started previously, the server should recognize this and "attach" the second client to the existing task instead of spooling up a new copy.

Now, each time any client queries the status of the task it's interested in, it does something along these lines:

```
var timeout = Task.Delay(numberOfSecondsUntilClientsPatienceRunsOut);
try
{
    var result = await Task.WhenAny(timeout, task);
    if (result == timeout)
    {
        // SNIP: No result is available yet. Just report the progress so far.
    }

    // SNIP: Report the result.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // SNIP: Report the error.
}
```

In short, it gives the task some reasonable time to finish what it's doing first, then falls back to reporting the on-going progress. This means there's a potentially significant window of time in which multiple clients could observe the same task failing.

My question is: if the task happens to throw during this window, is the exception observed (and handled) by all clients?

Comment: "The returned task will complete when any of the supplied tasks has completed. The returned task will always end in the `RanToCompletion` state with its `Result` set to the first task to complete. This is true even if the first task to complete ended in the Canceled or Faulted state." If `task` faults, and is completed, and more than one client is awaiting it through this construct, then all of them will see the faulted task. All of them will get an exception if they try to inspect the result of `task` (not `result`). It's not a "first come, first get" deal.

Comment: To simplify this further: if you await `Task.Run(() => throw new Exception(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))` multiple times in a row (with an exception handler), you will get an exception every single time, with the same time stamp (to prove the task isn't executing multiple times). One faulted task can produce as many exceptions as you like.

Comment: Interesting question, but easy enough to trivially test oneself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thank you. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.WhenAny` will not throw itself. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh194914):

> The returned task will complete when any of the supplied tasks has
>   completed. The returned task will always end in the `RanToCompletion`
>   state with its Result set to the first task to complete. This is true
>   even if the first task to complete ended in the `Canceled` or
>   `Faulted` state.

You will get back either `timeout` or `task`.

If the result is `task`, and you await that (or get `Task.Result`), and `task` has faulted, then that will throw. It doesn't matter how many callers do that, or when they do it -- attempting to get the result of a faulted task always throws. Simple code to demonstrate this:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => throw new Exception(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
try {
    await t;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
await Task.Delay(1000);
try {
    await t;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This will print the same timestamp, twice. The task only runs once, and only has one result, which produces an exception every time you try to get it. If you like you can mix in different threads or parallel calls, this doesn't change the outcome.

Note that in the case of a timeout, there is still the basic possibility of a race condition: two different tasks/threads, both awaiting the same task, may get different results on `await Task.WhenAny(timeout, task)`, based on which task they observe to complete first. In other words, even if `await Task.WhenAny(timeout, task) == timeout`, `task` can still have faulted at any point between `.WhenAny()` deciding it was done and control eventually returning to you. This is to be expected, and your code should handle this (on the next round of waiting, `.WhenAny()` would return immediately with the faulted task).